# Javascript play sound on click, second button click stop first sound

Tags: javascript, audio

I have this code that on button press it plays a sound, What I want is when one sound is playing from first click if you click another button before its over it stops the first one and plays the next one you clicked on.

Any ideas would be great.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Sounds</title>
</head>

<body>

<audio id="sound1" src="sounds/sound1.mp3"></audio>
<audio id="sound2" src="sounds/sound2.mp3"></audio>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('sound1').play()">Sound 1</button><br />
<button onclick="document.getElementById('sound2').play()">Sound 2</button><br />

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
<audio id="sound1" src="sounds/sound1.mp3"></audio>
<audio id="sound2" src="sounds/sound2.mp3"></audio>

<button onclick="playSound1()">Sound 1</button><br />
<button onclick="playSound2()">Sound 2</button><br />

<script type="text/javascript">
var audio1 = document.getElementById('sound1');
var audio2 = document.getElementById('sound2');
function playSound1(){
if (audio1.paused !== true){
    audio1.pause();
    audio2.play();
    }
else{
    audio2.play();
    }
}
function playSound2(){
if (audio2.paused !== true){
    audio2.pause();
    audio1.play();
    }
else{
    audio1.play();
    }
}
</script>
```

Though I would advice you use the [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) method on the button tag rather than the onclick attribute as it is more maintainable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put the id of the corresponding audio into a data-target attribute on a button. On load, get the buttons and assign a click handler that 
Reloads the current Audio, sets the current Audio element to the button's target, and plays the current Audio